# OSGI with Custom Class Loader Perm Gen Issue

Tags: osgi, classloader

For our purposes we didn't go with the standard OSGI jar reference that builds the jars into the bundle.  Rather for online upgrades, we wanted to be able to provide new and updated jars during upgrades.  Within our Activator class which starts and stops a bundle, we Implement our own URLClassLoader and then lookup all jars in a sub folder and supply to the URLClassLoader along with the OSGI CLassLoader as the parent.  This is great because now admins of the application can simply add jars to a classpath and restart the application(osgi restart, not actually shutting down jvm).  We got this working great.  Plus our bundle.jar doesn't get huge over time as all of the jar references are not included in the bundle jar.

However, now we have the ability to remotely restart the application using OSGI to do it within the same JVM.  However when the restart occurs, the class loader we added never gets garbage collected.  So if you restart the application like 10 times then it will blow the Perm Gen out of memory(Java 1.7).

We have tried to mimic what apache WebAppClassLoader does on unload but this didn't remove the references either.

I have scoured the internet for solutions to this and granted we are coding outside the typical OSGI implementation however is there not a way to clear the references to the ClassLoader.  After restart there honestly shouldn't be any references.

We have used MAT to analyze the heap dump but the referenced list of classes is always different.

Anyone know of a way to load external libraries a better way for use within OSGI?

Thanks for any information!

Comment: So we tried to remove using URLClassloader and simply rely totally on OSGI to manage the class loading.  We then tested this by starting and stopping the bundle numerous times and now instead of URLClassloader referencing all of the classes, the BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5 still shows references for each time we start and stop the bundle.

Comment: A class loader can only get garbage collected, if all of its classes are unreachable, which implies that also all instances of these classes are unreachable. If you have a leak, it doesn’t matter, how you change the class loader structure, you can only get rid of it by identifying the leak and fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java 8, there is no permanent generation in version 8.

Comment: We run into the same issue with Java 8.   Just takes longer to produce the out of memory because metaspace is defined within the heap in Java 8.